# Pandas keep duplicated with highest value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, duplicates

I have data similar to:

```
id value duplicate
a   200  yes
a   12   yes
b   42   yes
c   12   no
b   532  yes
b   21   yes
...
```

To track the duplicates I use `df['duplicate'] = df.duplicated('id', keep=False)` However, I would like to keep the ones with the highest `value` and either mark or drop the other duplicates. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

Ah I don't know why I didn't think of this first.
`df.sort(['id', 'value'])
df['is_duplicated'] = df.duplicated('id', keep='first')`

sorry!